# Protractor subLocator piping

Tags: xpath, protractor

I am trying to use | for getting child elements using below code

```
parent.element(
          by.xpath('.//button[normalize-space(text())="' + selector + '"] | .//*[contains(text(),"' + selector + '")]/following::button[1]')
        );
```

but the second part doesn't consider the context. Any solution?

Comment: Can you please share the html of the element. Is button a following sibling to the text containing element?

Comment: Hi.. 
The DOM is pretty big. Here is the problem
.// should actually identify the codes relative to the parent element which works fine for the left hand portion before |
But right hand portion searches the entire DOM and doesnt identity within the parent

Comment: And yes.. The xpath i am looking for should identiy buttons in 2 cases - based on the button text (first set) and based on the sibling before the button (2nd set)
And i need parent here because it should identify button on the modal too

Comment: i think you can use 'or' within '[...]' to evaluate either one of condition.

Comment: Are you sure it's searching from the beginning? I couldn't recreate the behavior with this code `it("check xpaths", async function(){
        await browser.get("https://angularjs.org/");

        const parent = $('div[app-run="todo.html"]');
        //first expath fails and the are  5 h2s on page but only one as child of parent
        const child = parent.element(by.xpath('.//h2[text()="Invalid"] | .//h2'));
        console.log(await child.getText());
    });`

Comment: @DublinDev You are right. Looks like an issue with my DOM and piping does work with context
Thank you for the help